# Remove packages from untrusted source and reinstall them

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a Kali Linux installed recently, but due to its inflexible mirror selection, all deb packages are downloaded from a mirror that I don't trust. Is it possible to tell apt / dselect to re-download and reinstall all packages, assuming sources.list has been updated to use new mirror?

Comment: `apt-get clean && apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -w 'install$' | cut -f 1)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Alex pointed out:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -w 'install$' | cut -f 1)
```

The first one makes sure apt's cache is empty. That way apt-get will need to download the packages from the repositories. The second, first you need a list of all installed packages, which is what the `$(...)` part is doing, and then you are using apt-get to reinstall them. There's another way with aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude --reinstall install '~i'
```

The `~i` search for "installed packages".

For both methods you will end without any automatically installed packages, so you must use `apt-mark showauto > packages` before doing this, and `sudo apt-mark auto $(cat packages)` to reestablish the list.

Comment: Urgh, actually I have accepted the answer too early. There are lots of dependency cycle problem so that certain packages have to be installed first. Anyway this is a good enough starting point.

Comment: For a somewhat full installation, these packages need to be installed first: `dpkg`, `debconf`, `liblocale-gettext-perl`, `gawk`, `foomatic-filters` (printing is not part of base system though). Then install all the remaining ones.

Comment: Both of these answers cause dependency cycles for me.

Comment: @mlissner that is a problem you had, not something my answer caused.

Comment: @braiam not sure, but figured I'd mention it in case others run into it. Makes sense to me that a command to reinstall everything might have cyclical dependencies.

Comment: @mlissner Actually no, ciclical dependencies are against Debian policy, if you found one, then the package is violating the policy and a bug must be filled.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Must be a relic of my bad update. I see what you're saying, thanks.

Comment: Simply `sudo aptitude reinstall '~i'` with aptitude 0.7.3

Comment: What about packages that have been install manually, say using a deb file?

Comment: @Sven if they they were manually downloaded, then you *implicitly trust them*.

Comment: @Braiam The aptitude command fails, cause it cannot download and reinstall the package. Is there a way to workaround that without uninstalling the packages?

Comment: @Sven `!?origin(debian)` could be?

Answer (score 0):

The answers here helped me solve the problem, this solution probably not the most efficient but gets the job done.

```
#!/bin/bash
for package in `dpkg --get-selections | grep -w 'install$' | cut -f 1`; do
    apt-get install --reinstall $package;
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this method of trying one-at-a-time gets around any errors from packages which can't be downloaded from apt repo.

Answer (score -1):

I used this script and was asked from time to time to give a Y(es)
Than the script went on.
But because it takes quite a while this makes the time to complete much longer. I changed the script with inserting `--yes force-yes`
Recommend forcing automatic def/old config acceptance as well

```
#!/bin/bash 
for package in `dpkg --get-selections | grep -w 'install$' | cut -f 1`; do
    apt-get --yes --force-yes -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install --reinstall $package
done
```